# How does an return object array gets copied into another array using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, methods, copy

Suppose i have a method returning an array, if I want to make a copy of this array using a for loop to copy each element:

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length;i++)
{
  copy[i] = someMethod()[i];
}
```

will this for loop redo someMethod every time we copy an element? Or does it perform the method and stores it somewhere and then copies each element to copy. 
I'm asking this question regarding an efficient runtime: In the first case, runtime could increase significantly if someMethod was a complicated method.

EDIT: Assume array.length refers to the length of the array returned by someMethod.

Comment: It will perform the call to `someMethod` every iteration.

Comment: Arrays are cloneable, so you can use `copy = someMethod().clone();`

Comment: what `array` are you using the length of? Is it as long as `copy` and will whatever `someMethod()` returns be just as long?

Comment: ah yes thats a mistake in creating an example of what type of problem i'm referring to. Assume array.length refers to the length of the array by someMethod

Comment: I cannot. How would you know that beforehand? As is, we can't even know if the length of the result of someMethod() can change between two adjacent calls of that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...will this for loop redo someMethod every time we copy an element?

Yes, creating a new array every time. The compiler or JVM won't rewrite the loop for you to make just one call. The JVM does a lot of optimizations, but (mostly) not changing the fundamental behavior you've specified in your code.

If you don't want the method re-run every iteration, don't call it in the loop body. Call it once prior to the loop and remember the array it returns, then use that.

Side note: See also the [`System.arraycopy` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

Comment: Is there a similar approach to using if someMethod would return a nested array?

Comment: @Allan Not only similar but exactly the same. Only be aware of if you need "deep copies".

Comment: So as long as the objects in my array are primitives, I can safely this method for nested arrays?

Comment: @Allan: I assume you mean you have an array of arrays, e.g. `int[][]` or similar. `arraycopy` copies values at the top level, just like your `for` loop does. In both cases (`arraycopy` and your `for` loop), if the array is of a reference type (an `int[][]` is an array of `int[]`, which is a reference type), the result will be a new array whose entries are references to the same arrays that the original array references. In both cases, if you want to copy *those* arrays as well, you'll need to do a *deep* copy. Your `for` loop, and `arraycopy`, do *shallow* copies.

Answer (score 0):

yes it calls someMethod() for every iteration of your loop. If you want to store the value returned, call someMethod() outside of your loop like this:

Note: I've tried to fix your syntax. Also you will need to make sure the copy array was properly initialized to the size you need.

```
someMethod();
for(int i=0; i < array.length;i++)
{
  copy[i] = *array*[i];
}
```